# Have DIV on same line

Tags: html

I have a question on the following html :

```
     <div id="HomeVideo"><a href="#"><img src="images/playvideoscreen3 copy.png" width="614" height="376" /></a></div>  
     <br />
     <div id='HomeVideo1'><a href="#"> 
        <img src="images/videoCamera_icon.png" border="0">
        </a>
     </div> 
     <div align="center"><a href="RequestInvite.aspx" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none"><span class="text2">Sign Up  Now</span></a>
     </div>
```

I like to have the Sign Up Now be in the same line as the videoCamera_Icon but not sure what I need to do. Note that putting it in the HomeVideo1 div will not be the answer as I have code connected to the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put both `#HomeVideo1` and "Sign Up Now" in the same container div and set their `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work as I have code on the click of #HomeVideo1.

Comment: That should not make a difference if they are both within a container.  This wouldn't alter your on click code.

Answer (score 0):

Div by default is a block level element that's why its adds up top and bottom margins. You can use css **display:inline** on div.

```
  <div id="HomeVideo"><a href="#"><img src="images/playvideoscreen3 copy.png" width="614" height="376" /></a></div>  
     <br />
     <div id='HomeVideo1' style="display:inline;"><a href="#"> 
        <img src="images/videoCamera_icon.png" border="0">
        </a>
     </div> 
     <div align="center" style="display:inline;"><a href="RequestInvite.aspx" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none"><span class="text2">Sign Up  Now</span></a>
     </div>
```

You can also add **display:inline-block** instead of inline